# can we get foreign key value in data object vue.js

Tags: vue.js

it is possible to assign the foreign key value into the variable in data object in vue.js?
What i want to do is to get the current user_id and work_id to save into the database. user_id & work_id is foreign key from different table.

```
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return{
          editmode: false,
          works:{},
          index:1,
          form: new Form({
            work_name:'',
            description:'',
            payment:'',
            location:'',
            end_date:'',
                       }),
          work_id:'1', //how to get work_id that i choose?
          user_id:'1', //how to get the current user id?   
        }
      },
      methods:{
        editModel(work){
          this.editmode = false;
          this.form.reset();
          $('#addNewModal').modal('show')
          this.form.fill(work);
        },
        loadWork(){
          if(this.$gate.isChairman()){
            axios.get('api/work').then(({data})=>(this.works = data));
          }
        },
        createApplication(){
          this.$Progress.start(); 
          axios.post('api/application',{application:'apply', user_id:this.user_id, work_id:this.work_id}).then(()=>{Fire.$emit('AfterEvent');

          $('#addNewModal').modal('hide')
          Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Work Application success'
          })

           this.$Progress.finish();
          })
          .catch(()=>{
            this.$Progress.fail();
          })
        } 
      },
        created() {
            this.loadWork();
            Fire.$on('AfterEvent',() => {this.loadWork()});
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to store `user_id` & `work_id` into the variable in data object in `loadWork()` methods?

Comment: Yes, and i want to use the value of user_id & work_id in createApplication() method. From the code above..i succeed to get the value "1" but i need the user_id= current user_id and work_id = work_id that i choose in the view list. Im new to this vue.js

Comment: Did you mean work_id can be changed by user?

Comment: Yes. user can change the work_id based on the list of posts in the view

Comment: `user_id` and `work_id` were initialized in `loadWork()` and being send to server in `createApplication()`.  For `work_id`, users can change it maybe by `v-model`. It seems no problems, I don't know which part you can't resolve?

Comment: I having problem to assign  the value to the variable work_id and user_id in that data object. I mean how to get the desired data and save it into that variable?

Comment: Certainly, you need to know which column in `api/work` is correspond to `work_id` and `user_id`. Maybe it would be like `this.work_id = data.work_id`、`this.user_id = data.user_id` in `then` block of `loadWork()`.

Comment: thanks. it work but Im getting Array to string conversion error.

Comment: I guessed the error is caused by the structure of your data from API.